# LT Spice cant find definition of model

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, bjt, ltspice, simulation

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

I have designed a operational amplifier in Lt spice as shown in the 1st image. I changed the name of the BJT models as I wanted to change the beta value.

2nd image shows the symbol of the op amp

3rd image shows another schematic where I am testing the op amp. When I try to run it, it gives an error as shown in the 4th image.

I have watched many videos and tried many solutions I found on the internet but nothing works. Can someone advise?
Thank you

Comment: Do you have a ".MODEL" for the MYNPN?

Comment: I am afraid I have no idea what that is. All I did was changed the npn and pnp to suit the beta I needed. Now it doesnt work.

Comment: Well, your 4th image shows an error message which wants "MYNPN" defined. To do that, you need a .MODEL card. Perhaps you need to learn a few things about Spice?

Comment: Definitely jonk. Newbie here. Perhaps you could teach me?

Comment: Perhaps my better recommendation is that you buy and read, *"The Spice Book,"* by Andrei Vladimirescu. Things don't get much better than that book!

Comment: Please use the built-in image uploader. It uses imgur, too, but it makes sure that the pictures remain there for reference across the years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a little bit of an obscure error telling you that `ako` is not allowed inside `.subckt` definitions -- they must be in the top level schematic, only.

The solution, if you have to use those transistors, is to:

- <kbd>RClick</kbd> on a transistor, select the row of the desired transistor, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> -- this will copy the `.model` definition
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice, to avoid making changes to the transistor
- <kbd>S</kbd> to bring up the SPICE directive editor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the copied `.model`
- before pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, modify the name to be `MyNPN`, or `MyPNP`, or whatever name you wish
- make whatever other modifications to the parameters
- either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the `OK` button
- <kbd>LClick</kbd> to place the SPICE directive in the schematic

This goes the same way for both the NPNs and the PNPs. Or, if those transistors are not mandatory, simply add your own `.model` definition for each, but not with the `ako` flag. Now it should work.

However, looking over your schematic, it looks like you prepared `V(a)` and `V(b)` but they are not used anywhere. They will also reside inside the subcircuit, together with the power supplies -- this is not usually done, but that doesn't mean you can't go wild with it, topology included.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks a lot.